# Should we remove batteries from electronic devices when not in use?

Tags: battery, electronics

When I bought a digital camera recently, the shopkeeper advised me "to remove the batteries when the camera is not used for a long time".

I have heard this kind of thing for other devices also (like torch).

Does having these devices with batteries in it(with full charge), kept idle for a long time damage the device ?

Comment: I always thought it's to prevent damage due to battery leak: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc-carbon_battery#Leakage_and_environmental_concerns http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_battery#Leaks

Comment: When I did this least, my camera's internal clock reseted to something like 2006. Since them I let the battery in (apart from the short time when I'm switching it against a new one).

Answer (score 13):

Many devices when turned off still use a bit of power (e.g. to detect when the on button is pushed when there is no real physical power cutoff) leading them to become dead sooner than when you had removed them when you don't need the device.

As vartec mentioned battery leaking can be damaging to the electronics, depending on the design of the battery compartment

[Here's an Knol article about it.](http://knol.google.com/k/everything-you-need-to-know-about-primary-battery-leakage#)

> When carbon or alkaline batteries have become discharged, the
>   chemistry of the cells will degrade and some hydrogen gas will be
>   generated.  This out-gassing will result in increasing pressure within
>   the battery.  Eventually, the excess pressure will either rup- ture
>   the insulating seals at the end of the battery, or bulge and rupture
>   the outer metal canister, or both.  When this happens, an acidic (for
>   carbon cells) or caustic (for alka- line cells) electrolyte gel will
>   ooze from the battery.
>
> -snip-
>
> **The leaking electrolyte can corrode the metal housing and battery
>   contacts of a simple flashlight, and it can damage or destroy the
>   delicate circuitry of an expensive electronic flashlight.** 
>   Furthermore, swelling of the battery canisters can render one or more
>   of the batteries hopelessly jammed within the flashlight body.  One
>   leaking battery can cause a chain failure, when its leaking goo
>   corrodes the adjacent ones so that they then leak. A five dollar set
>   of dead batteries can and will destroy a five hundred dollar
>   instrument if you let them.

Comment: Yup - had that happen to a radio and a torch:-)

Comment: +1, abandoned electronic wrist watches often meet their death this way.

Comment: had it happen to an expensive flashlight, sadly. And during normal use too, though in extreme conditions (very hot weather, shooting for extended periods, causing the thing to get very hot and putting high strain on the batteries, higher apparently than they'd been designed for).